# Multiple selectors on click function, how to know which selector was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, multiple-select-query

new to Jquery here. I have four selectors on a click function, see code below, this is because I want the same effect happening on all of them when clicked, instead of making a click function for all four selectors. However, when clicked I want the function to identify which selector was clicked so I can perform an action on one of the selectors, this is why I use id's instead of a class. More precise, I want to set the CSS on a clicked selector to a higher z-index value so it will not be effected by the effect that will be taking place, in this case I want the clicked selector to have an z-index value of 10.

I tried using a if statement, see below, but it's not working, anyone know how to do this?

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
```

My jQuery attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

var effect = $("#slide");

$("#1, #2, #3, #4").click(function() {

    effect.animate({width: "1100px"}, 200, "easeOutQuint");
    $("#2").data('clicked', true);

    if ($("#2").data('clicked')) {
       $("#2").css("z-index", "10");
    }

});
});
```

Comment: `e.target` use for this

Comment: Use `this` to refer to element whicn invoked the handler

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `this` within your `click` callback to determine the clicked element:

```
$("#1, #2, #3, #4").click(function() {
    effect.animate({width: "1100px"}, 200, "easeOutQuint");
    $(this).data('clicked', true);

    if ($(this).data('clicked')) {
        $(this).css("z-index", "10");
    }
});
```

However, in order to make it work, you don't need use IDs. It is a much better idea to use one common class instead of IDs if possible:

```
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

And in JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var effect = $("#slide");

    $(".myClass").click(function() {
        effect.animate({width: "1100px"}, 200, "easeOutQuint");
        $(this).data('clicked', true);

        if ($(this).data('clicked')) {
           $(this).css("z-index", "10");
        }
    });
});
```

Note that there is not much sense in your `if ($(this).data('clicked'))` condition. Since you set `clicked` to `true` right before condition, it will always be `true`.

Comment: They aren't invalid in HTML5, it's also not necessary for them to be classes (*I recommend clarifying that it's a better idea to use classes*).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek oh, thanks. I have removed this part :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` keyword:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

var effect = $("#slide");

$("#1, #2, #3, #4").click(function() {

    effect.animate({width: "1100px"}, 200, "easeOutQuint");
    $(this).data('clicked', true);

    if ($(this).data('clicked')) {
       $(this).css("z-index", "10");
    }

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.target`:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

var effect = $("#slide");

$("#1, #2, #3, #4").click(function(event) {

    effect.animate({width: "1100px"}, 200, "easeOutQuint");
    $("#2").data('clicked', true);

    if($(event.target).attr("id") == "2" ){
       $("#2").css("z-index", "10");
    }

});
});
```

Edit based on @Spencer Wieczorek comment, if you want the clicked input to have a `z-index` of 10 then:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

var effect = $("#slide");

$("#1, #2, #3, #4").click(function(event) {

    effect.animate({width: "1100px"}, 200, "easeOutQuint");
    $("#2").data('clicked', true);

    $(event.target).css("z-index", "10");
});
});
```

Comment: *" I want the clicked selector to have an z-index value of 10"*

Answer (score 0):

**May be this will help you or you can also use switch case**

```
$("#1, #2, #3, #4").click(function() {

if($(this).attr("id") == "1"){
//do sth
}else if($(this).attr("id") == "2"){
//do sth
}else{
//
}

});
```

OR

Comment: That method would be really redundant in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add ids to all the divs only to the z-index one and then use the jquery `attr()` function

To get the id of the current clicked item (`$(this)` refers to the curent clicked item) and add the z-index if condition is true
try this:

```
<div></div>
<div id="zindex"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>


   $(document).ready(function(e) {

    var effect = $("#slide");

    $("div").click(function() {

        effect.animate({width: "1100px"}, 200, "easeOutQuint");
        if ($(this).attr('id') == "zindex") {
           $(this).css("z-index", "10");
        }

    });
    });
```

see jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/596w1hwr/